# Sending data to input form with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to send data into the input text-field on this site https://www.vtinfo.com/PF/product_finder.asp. I am not able to figure out how to do it.

I have tried using the [FormRequest](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects) method but it didn't work

Comment: I suggest to use selenium for this case.

Comment: By the forms method do you mean you tried using a [`FormRequest`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects)?

Comment: yeah FormRequest

Comment: @IbtsamCh maybe if you give some example code of what you have tried we might be able to help